# Unexpected namespace declaration

Tags: xslt, saxon

I'm porting old transformations to a new transformation platform (based on Saxon 9.9). I have an issue where the new platform creates slightly different results than the old platform (based on an ancient bug-ridden Oracle XSLT1+ implementation).

Consider the following source document:

```
<root xmlns="http://root.invalid">
  <model xmlns="http://root.invalid">
    <keys>
      <id xmlns:foo="http://foo.invalid" foo:nil="true"/>
    </keys>
    <instance>
      <id xmlns:foo="http://foo.invalid" foo:nil="true"/>
      <whatever type="String">whatever</whatever>
    </instance>
  </model>
</root>
```

When the following transformation is applied:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:root="http://root.invalid"
  exclude-result-prefixes="root"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="root:id">
    <id xmlns:foo="http://foo.invalid" foo:nil="true" type="String">1234</id>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following (correct) output is generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://root.invalid">
  <model>
    <keys>
      <id xmlns:foo="http://foo.invalid" xmlns="" foo:nil="true" type="String">1234</id>
    </keys>
    <instance>
      <id xmlns:foo="http://foo.invalid" xmlns="" foo:nil="true" type="String">1234</id>
      <whatever type="String">whatever</whatever>
    </instance>
  </model>
</root>
```

The problem here is that in the new platform I get a `xmlns=""` namespace definition that didn't exists in the old platform (that is breaking existing consumers of the output transformation).

Can you explain why the `xmlns=""` appers here and is there any chance I could get:

```
<id xmlns:foo="http://foo.invalid" foo:nil="true" type="String">1234</id>
```

instead (with Saxon 9.9 based XSLT)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your result element(s) to be in that namespace then use e.g. `xmlns="http://root.invalid"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` or at least on the literal result `id` elements e.g. `<id xmlns="http://root.invalid" .../>`. Or use an `xsl:copy` and add the new attribute and text e.g. `<xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/><xsl:attribute name="type">string</xsl:attribute>1234</xsl:copy>` in your template matching the `id` elements.

Comment: This answer was accepted because it introduced a "work-around" to mimic the behavior of the old platform. If you upvote this answer please upvote the answer by @MichaelKay too.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the `id` element using the literal result element in the stylesheet:

```
<id xmlns:foo="http://foo.invalid" foo:nil="true" type="String">1234</id>
```

and the in-scope namespaces for this element also include

```
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:root="http://root.invalid"
```

The specification for literal result elements says that

(a) the expanded name (uri + local) of the element in the result tree must be the same as the expanded name of the literal result element: that is (no namespace, "id").

(b) the in-scope namespace bindings of the element in the result tree should include all in-scope namespaces of the literal result element, other than any excluded namespace bindings. The excluded namespace bindings are those for "xsl" and "root"; this leaves the binding for "foo" which is therefore present in the result.

The reason the `xmlns=""` is generated is that it is the only way to meet the requirement that the `id` element should be in no namespace. If it were not generated, the `id` element would be in the namespace `"http://root.invalid"`.

If you don't want the `xmlns=""`, that probably means you want the `id` element to be in the namespace `"http://root.invalid"`, and you can achieve this by adding the declaration `xmlns="http://root.invalid"` to the literal result element in the stylesheet.

I can't comment on why the Oracle XDK got this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This rule, based on the answer by @MartinHonnen, produced the wanted results:

```
<xsl:template match="root:id">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">string</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:text>1234</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```